# find the character ~ 's first occurence that is in the middle of the url

Tags: regex

I need to retrieve certain portion of an url using regex. The url looks like this:

```
/xxxx/bbbb/good/city/games_in_the_city.~cccccc~dddddd~eeeee.html
```

I need to retrieve games_in_the_city. I got the first portion until the / removed. Now need to find the first occurence of ~ in the string so that the rest can be removed as well. 
The regex that I have right now `(.*\/good\/city\/)(.*)(\.html)` gets  `games_in_the_city.~cccccc~dddddd~eeeee`

How can I modify my regex so `~cccccc~dddddd~eeeee` can be removed as well. The final output should be `games_in_the_city`
I will not know how many `~` (tilde) can appear in the url. sometimes it might one to n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
(?:.*\/good\/city\/)(.*?)\.?(?:~[^~]+)*(?:\.html)
```

[See it](http://www.rubular.com/r/jIhm9QAylg)